# require(header) not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have begun to build a site in which I use php to require a standard header page for all of the subsequent pages. The header is simple, setting up the nav bar and logo, etc. The require("header.php") works fine for some pages. However, I have attached one page in an  tag href and when I click to transfer to the href page, the header is not carried over. currently, all I have in the page I am trying to use as an href is the following:

```
<?
require('database_header.php');
?>
```

This properly loads in the other pages, but as an href it seems to be malfunctioning. any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you have short tags enabled? What do you see when you inspect the page source on your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `PHP Short tags`. Change this -

```
<?php
  require('database_header.php');
?>
```

**OR** set below in php.ini

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: In addition, I don't think this is a case of deliberately using short tags as much as it is NOT knowing what else uses <? and how this can confuse the program.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it. I am rather new to this and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error. Add this code just after php tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then inspect source of your website. Have you got all the files in the same dir? If no, there can be a broken path. Anyway, errors should say you the reason. If require fails, php generates error.